# Two questions about a simple mystery function involving pointers

Tags: c, pointers, memory, reference, memory-address

My class is currently studying pointers in C and we were asked to explain what the below function does given a array and it's length. I currently understand that it creates a pointer, *x, that points to the first element in the array, then it creates the other pointer, *y, which points to the end of the array. However the rest I don't understand. I'll sum up my questions:

1st: What is the while loop checking for? In other words, what does (x < y) mean? Shouldn't it be (*x < *y)?

2nd: Does the while loop simply inverse the array? If so, how does the x and y values increment? I don't see any way for the *x and *y to reference any elements other than the first and last element in the array.

```
void mystery(int arr[], int len) {
    int *x = arr;
    int *y = arr + len - 1;
    while (x < y) {
        int t = *x;
        *x = *y;
        *y = t;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for providing your insight and knowledge.

Comment: Have you tried executing this?

Comment: Better yet, execute it using a debugger.

Comment: The problem with your `while` loop is that `x` will (most likely) always be less than `y` resulting in a infinite loop.

Comment: Is this code complete? I'm with you on the confusion. The while loop will never exit (as long as len > 1).

Comment: Hard to say what the code *should* be if one does know what it is supposed to do.

Comment: Given the constraints of what you're "given" (an array and a length), what this does "does" is one of: (a) return directly when the length is 1, (b) invoke undefined behavior when the length is less than  1 (including negative lengths, which this allows without any sort of validation or remorse), or (c) spin infinitely when the length is greater than 1. That's it. In short, if asked what this code "is", the simple answer is "crap". What it "does" is entirely dependent on the input given.

Comment: @WhozCraig Not necessarily undefined behavior on negative `len`: `int arr[5]; mystery(&arr[3], -1);` :D

Comment: There are some missing ++ operators *somewhere*...

Comment: @Kevin Yeah, I guess I read too much into the OP's statement "given a array and it's length" as opposed to "some arbitrary element address within an array and its length". It's a world gone mad.

Comment: Did you retype this code (bad) or copy and paste it (good)?

Comment: This is the exact code given to me by the instructor. Copied and pasted in all it's glory. I did compile and run it; however, I wasn't able to use the debugger very effectively since I'm still understanding how to use CLION and its debugger (GDB from Cygwin).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> … it creates a pointer, *x,…

No, `x` is the pointer. `*x` is what it points to.

> … what does (x < y) mean?

`x < y` tests whether `x` points to something *earlier* than `y`. (This is only defined if `x` and `y` point into the same array, structure, or union.) In an array, an element is earlier than another if it has a lower index. In a structure, a member is earlier than another if it is declared earlier in the structure definition. In a union, no member is earlier than any other.

> Does the while loop simply inverse the array?

The loop is broken code. It never alters `x` or `y`, so it never changes whether the condition `x < y` evaluates to true, so, if the loop is entered, it never terminates. It looks like code that might have been intended to reverse the elements of the array. If you change it to:

```
while (x < y)
{
   int t = *x;
   *x++ = *y;
   *y-- = t;
}
```

then, in each iteration, it advances `x` and retards `y`. At the middle of the array, they will be equal (if there are an odd number of elements) or will cross (if there are an even number of elements). Either way, `x < y` will then be false, and the loop will stop, having swapped each element in the front with the element in the reflected position in the rear, thus reversing the array contents.

Comment: Thank you! This confirmed my suspicion that this code didn't do anything that would be considered useful. I was looking for meaning that wasn't there! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The above function as is does not reverse the array as `x` and `y` do not change causing the program to be stuck at the `while` loop.

To resolve the issue, the pointer `x` should be incremented while the pointer `y` should be decremented. When they become equal, the expression inside the while loop evaluates to false thereby breaking the loop.

The loop should look like the following:

```
while(x < y) 
{
    int t = *x;
    *x++ = *y;
    *y-- = t;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This confirmed my suspicion that this code didn't do anything that would be considered useful. I was looking for meaning that wasn't there! Thanks guys!